# Modifying a Loop to Show More

Tags: loop

This loop shows one featured post above 4 post titles from a certain category that is specified in the theme options.

What I would like to do is show all 4 posts from the 4 titles, above the 4 titles.

The 4 titles are from this snippet of code

```
<a class="listtitle" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpnewspaper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

The full loop code is here.

```
<div class="col">
<?php gab_dynamic_sidebar('Subnews1');?>

<?php
$postnr = of_get_option('of_wn_nr8') + of_get_option('of_wn_nr8a');
if (intval($postnr) > 0 ) { ?>
    <span class="catname"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8'));?>"><?php echo get_cat_name(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8')); ?></a></span>
    <?php
    $count = 1;
    $args = array(
     'post__not_in'=>$do_not_duplicate,
      'posts_per_page' => $postnr,
      'cat' => of_get_option('of_wn_cat8', 1)
    );
    $gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query($args); 
    while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post(); if (of_get_option('of_dnd') == 1) { $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; }
    ?>
    <div class="featuredpost<?php if($count == of_get_option('of_wn_nr8') or $count == $postnr) { echo ' lastpost'; } ?>">


        <?php if ($count <= of_get_option('of_wn_nr8')) { ?>

            <h2 class="posttitle">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpnewspaper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </h2>                       
            <div class="opinion_wrapper">
            <?php
                gab_media(array(   'imgtag' => 1,   'link' => 1,
                    'name' => 'wn-subnews',
                    'enable_video' => 0,
                    'catch_image' => of_get_option('of_catch_img', 0),
                    'enable_thumb' => 1,
                    'resize_type' => 'c',
                    'media_width' => 120, 
                    'media_height' => 103, 
                    'thumb_align' => 'alignleft',
                    'enable_default' => 0
                ));
            ?>  
            <div class="opinion_marker"><!-- opinion marker --></div>                   
            </div>
            <p><?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(),27); ?>&hellip;</p>

            <?php gab_postmeta(); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>

            <a class="listtitle" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpnewspaper' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php } ?>

    </div><!-- .featuredpost -->
    <?php $count++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I photoshopped it to be more clear http://d.pr/i/hCd2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting `$count` equal to 4 on line 8? Like this:

```
<div class="col">
<?php gab_dynamic_sidebar('Subnews1');?>

<?php
$postnr = of_get_option('of_wn_nr8') + of_get_option('of_wn_nr8a');
if (intval($postnr) > 0 ) { ?>
    <span class="catname"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8'));?>"><?php echo get_cat_name(of_get_option('of_wn_cat8')); ?></a></span>
    <?php
    $count = 4;
    // etc
```